# Angular directive inline controller vs registered controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been trying to find out if one is better than the other.

Basically, in AngularJS directives, what's the difference of using inline controller:

```
.directive(function(){
    return{
        controller: function (){}
    }
});
```

as oppose to registering a controller and reference it:

```
.directive(function(){
    return{
        controller: 'someController'
    }
})
.controller('someController', function(){});
```

The controller is only used in the directive and no where else. Is there any performance gain doing inline? What's the difference?
Any information would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: No difference. Its just a different programming preference.

Comment: Hmm. But one is actually registering the controller with a name and can be accessed globally. Does that not make any sort of memory difference?

Comment: No. 100%. It only allows you to reuse.

Comment: Nice. Thank you for the information!